# Cross-platform NSValue category

Tags: ios, cocoa, cgpoint, cgsize, nsvalue

I am trying to create a cross-platform NSValue category that will handle CGPoint/NSPoint and CGSize/NSSize etc, for Cocoa and iOS.

I have this:

```
#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
// Mac OSX

+ (NSValue *) storePoint:(NSPoint)point {
  return [NSValue valueWithPoint:point];
}

+ (NSPoint) getPoint {
  return (NSPoint)[self pointValue];
}


#else
// iOS

+ (NSValue *) storePoint:(CGPoint)point {
  return [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
}

+ (CGPoint) getPoint {
  return (CGPoint)[self CGPointValue];
}


#endif
```

The Mac part works perfectly but the iOS part gives me an error on

```
  return (CGPoint)[self CGPointValue];
```

with two messages: 1) no known class method for selector CGPointValue and  "used type CGPoint (aka struct CGPoint) where arithmetic or pointer type is required.

why is that?

Comment: there's no CGPointValue method on NSValue class. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @HutinPuylo There is in the [iOS rendition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @HutinPuylo it is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/CGPointValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `+[NSValue CGPointValue]` does not exist you want `-[NSValue CGPointValue]`

```
#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
// Mac OSX

+ (NSValue *) storePoint:(NSPoint)point {
  return [NSValue valueWithPoint:point];
}

- (NSPoint) getPoint { // this should be instance method
  return (NSPoint)[self pointValue];
}


#else
// iOS

+ (NSValue *) storePoint:(CGPoint)point {
  return [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
}

- (CGPoint) getPoint { // this should be instance method
  return (CGPoint)[self CGPointValue];
}


#endif
```

Comment: ahhh, ok, but out of curiosity, why Xcode is not giving me any error when I compile for Cocoa?

Comment: @RubberDuck I don't know... maybe somehow Xcode think `self` is `id` (untyped) so no type check was performed

Answer (score 1):

To make things even simpler, just create a category that is only for iOS and use the same method names as on OS X, since for OS X CGPoint & NSPoints are the same you don't need more, and you don't have to modify your OS X code.

```
@implementation NSValue (XCross)
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
+ (NSValue *) valueWithPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    return [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
}

- (CGPoint) pointValue {
    return [self CGPointValue];
}
#endif
@end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
+ (CGPoint) getPoint {
  return (CGPoint)[self CGPointValue];
}
```

Your variable begin by a maj ? isn't it better to set your variable with min. It may be a problem with CGPoint class.

```
[self cgPointValue];
```

Comment: No. This [is a Cocoa method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html). You cannot just change the name. The issue is that it's an instance method, not a class method.